# using simple regex quantifier expression in grep

Tags: grep, regular-expression

Does anyone know why `ls | xargs -n 1 basename | grep -E '[0-9]{1}'` does not only show occurrences of a single digit between 0-9?

For example if I have:

```
touch 1
touch 22
touch 333
touch test_file
```

If I run `ls | xargs -n 1 basename | grep -P '[0-9]{1}'`:

I get 1, 22 and 333 files listed.

If I run `ls | xargs -n 1 basename | grep -P '[0-9]{2}'`:

I get 22 and 333 files listed.

I would expect the {2} to only show the 22 file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the reason you are expecting something different than what is happening is that you are taking

```
[0-9]{n}
```

to mean match only exactly n occurrences of characters in [0-9] and throw the rest away, when what its doing is finding n occurrences of characters in [0-9] and calling it a match.  So in

```
[0-9]{1}
```

it finds any exactly one occurrence of something matching [0-9] so 1 matches, then when examining the 22, it stops at the first 2 and considers it a match without looking at the rest.  Similarly for the 333.  If you specified

```
[0-9]{2}
```

it would not match 1, but 22 matches, and then the 33 in 333 matches so it grabs it.

As slm said, word boundaries are the ticket here.  You have both the -P and the -E flavors of grep regex matching in your question.  You can use the GNU \< and \> with -E like this:

```
ls | xargs -n 1 basename | grep -E '\<[0-9]{1}\>'
```

or the \b with the either -E or the pcre matching -P like this

```
ls | xargs -n 1 basename | grep -P '\b[0-9]{1}\b'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `grep -x` to find exact matches instead of finding matches inside lines.

`grep foo` finds lines that contain `foo`, while `grep -x foo` finds line that *are* `foo`.

Same thing, `grep -E '[0-9]{1}'` (same as `grep '[0-9]'`) finds lines that contain one digit. `grep -xE '[0-9]{1}'` finds lines that consist of one digit.

With GNU `grep`, you can use the `--color` or `-o` options to see what is being matched though it will show you all the matches.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the first two chars of `333` match the regex, so the whole line matches.

If you want to avoid that you could use:

```
(^|[^0-9])[0-9]{2}([^0-9]|$)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the contents of your examples in a text file you can see why `grep` is matching it:

```
$ grep -E '[0-9]{1}' file.txt
touch 1
touch 22
touch 333
```

You can use word boundaries (`-w`) to tell `grep` that you want to only match a single word of your regex (`\<REGEX\>`) rather than any string that happens to match it:

```
$ grep -Ew '\<[0-9]{1}\>' file.txt
touch 1

$ grep -Ew '\<[0-9]{2}\>' file.txt
touch 22

$ grep -Ew '\<[0-9]{3}\>' file.txt
touch 333
```

The `\<` and `\>` tell `grep` where the boundaries are. This forces `grep` to match explicit words such as 1 but not strings such as 11, 111, or aa11aa, since the regex within these strings isn't contained by word boundaries.